# i got handler is not a function when close my app, i am using AppState

Tags: react-native

I am using AppState on react-native so i can know when my application active or on the background. I can get active state with AppState but i cannot get background State because when i double back my application to close it, it will produce error Handler is not function.

I am already ask to github but the answer is not work and they close the thread, so annoy https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/24383

this is my code:

```
class SplashScreen extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = ({
            appState : AppState.currentState,
        })
    }

    fetchingAll = async (state) => {
        if(state == 'active'){
            await this.props.getEquipmentTier();
            await this.props.getEquipmentCraft();
            await this.props.getMapData();
            await this.props.getMonsterLocation();
            await this.props.getMonsterElement();
            await this.props.getMonsterDrop();
            await this.props.getItemData();
            await this.props.getCardData();
            await this.props.getEquipmentData();
            await this.props.getMonsterdata();
        }
        return true;
    }


    componentWillMount() {
        AppState.addEventListener('change', this.fetchingAll(this.state.appState));
    }


//If i am include this (componentDidUnMount) on my code the MainMenu will show loading becuse this.props.navigation.addListener('DidFocus', () => {
)
not execute.

/*componentWillUnMount() {
        AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.fetchingAll(this.state.appState));
    }*/

    componentDidUpdate(){
        if (!this.props.isLoading) {
            this.props.navigation.dispatch(resetAction);
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <ImageBackground
                source={require('../style/images/launch_screen.png')}
                style={{flex: 1}}
                resizeMode='stretch'
            >
                <View style={style.imageFullScreen}>
                    <StatusBar hidden/>
                    <ActivityIndicator
                        size="large"
                        color="#00796b"
                    />
                    <Text style={style.indicatorText}>Please wait ...</Text>
                </View>
            </ImageBackground>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        isLoading: state.MonsterReducer.isLoading,
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        getMonsterdata: () => dispatch(fetchingMonsterFromAPI()),
        getEquipmentData: () => dispatch(fetchingEquipmentFromAPI()),
        getCardData: () => dispatch(fetchingCardFromAPI()),
        getItemData: () => dispatch(fetchingItemFromAPI()),
        getMonsterDrop: () => dispatch(fetchingMonsterDropFromAPI()),
        getMonsterElement: () => dispatch(fetchingMonsterElementFromAPI()),
        getMapData: () => dispatch(fetchingMapFromAPI()),
        getMonsterLocation: () => dispatch(fetchingMonsterLocationFromAPI()),
        getEquipmentCraft: () => dispatch(fetchingEquipmentCraftFromAPI()),
        getEquipmentTier: () => dispatch(fetchingEquipmentTierFromAPI()),
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SplashScreen);
```

i except that i can close the App and get the background state.
FYI, i am using redux navigation with backHandler, i dont know if it effect with the AppState or not but i know that those 2 function using handler,

Comment: `AppState.addEventListener('change', this.fetchingAll);` and `AppState.removeEventListener('change', this.fetchingAll);` instead. You should also do all those things in a `await Promise.all([...])` instead of each one sequentially, unless they need to be done in order.

Comment: so you mean i don't need to passing the state?
becuase the function need state varibale right. 
and yes they need to do in order.
fetchingAll = async (state) => {

Comment: [`AppState`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/appstate) passes the next state to the callback function for you, which reminds me, you should also call `this.setState({ appState: state });` at the end of `fetchingAll()` if you want to keep your state variable from going stale.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts sorry but it not work if i not pass this.state.appState then dispatch never execute and it straight go to componentDidUpdate, but because in componentDidUpdate there is this.props.isLoading so it stuck on it, and show the render which is activityindicator. i am stuck 2 days because of this,

Comment: They gave you the same answer I did. What you think is the problem is probably not even related to whatever issue you’re having. The correct way to add the listener is what we’ve told you.

Comment: thank you for your answer yes, i know it the correct way to add the listener, but it not work with it maybe there is something else with my code that make this problem happen, i search on the google for error "handler is not function" but i dont get correct answer, so i will look for my code one by one and i found the solution i will post it on the answer. thank you for your help

Comment: @AndySuwito Did you find the solution? I'm facing the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I also bumped into this. For me it was because I had called `AppState.addEventListener` and `AppState.removeEventListener` and referenced a non-existant handler.